# PrepareForSege crash when not using auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, viewcontroller

I have two Xcode projects, the first called `blank`, new and using auto layout (default). The second is called `test` and is not using auto layout (iPhone layout instead).

On the test project, the method `prepareForSegue` crashes :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        /*The program crashed here */ DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
        [controller setDetailItem:object];
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =     self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
    }
}
```

There are no differences in the code between the two project except in the XML file of the storyboard.

Storyboard of `blank` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="9532" systemVersion="15D21" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="H1p-Uh-vWS">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="9530"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Master-->
        <scene sceneID="pY4-Hu-kfo">
            <objects>
                <navigationController title="Master" id="RMx-3f-FxP" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Pmd-2v-anx">
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="7bK-jq-Zjz" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="tsl-Nk-0bq"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="8fS-aE-onr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-38" y="-630"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Detail-->
        <scene sceneID="yUG-lL-AsK">
            <objects>
                <viewController title="Detail" id="JEX-9P-axG" customClass="DetailViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="SYR-Wa-9uf"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="GAO-Cl-Wes"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="svH-Pt-448">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" text="Detail view content goes here" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" minimumFontSize="10" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0XM-y9-sOw">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="292" width="560" height="17"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" size="system"/>
                                <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="0XM-y9-sOw" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="svH-Pt-448" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="Tsc-yG-G1q"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="0XM-y9-sOw" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="svH-Pt-448" secondAttribute="centerY" id="jWN-iV-94e"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="0XM-y9-sOw" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="tHV-ZD-HQj"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="Detail" id="mOI-FS-AaM"/>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="detailDescriptionLabel" destination="0XM-y9-sOw" id="deQ-Na-JPF"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="FJe-Yq-33r" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="709" y="129"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Split View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="Nki-YV-4Qg">
            <objects>
                <splitViewController id="H1p-Uh-vWS" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="RMx-3f-FxP" kind="relationship" relationship="masterViewController" id="BlO-5A-QYV"/>
                        <segue destination="vC3-pB-5Vb" kind="relationship" relationship="detailViewController" id="Tll-UG-LXB"/>
                    </connections>
                </splitViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="cZU-Oi-B1e" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-856" y="-330"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Master-->
        <scene sceneID="smW-Zh-WAh">
            <objects>
                <tableViewController title="Master" clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear="NO" id="7bK-jq-Zjz" customClass="MasterViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="r7i-6Z-zg0">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <prototypes>
                            <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="blue" hidesAccessoryWhenEditing="NO" indentationLevel="1" indentationWidth="0.0" reuseIdentifier="Cell" textLabel="Arm-wq-HPj" style="IBUITableViewCellStyleDefault" id="WCw-Qf-5nD">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="86" width="600" height="44"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="WCw-Qf-5nD" id="37f-cq-3Eg">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="43.5"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" text="Title" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="Arm-wq-HPj">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="15" y="0.0" width="570" height="43.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="20"/>
                                            <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                            <color key="highlightedColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                        </label>
                                    </subviews>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <segue destination="vC3-pB-5Vb" kind="showDetail" identifier="showDetail" id="6S0-TO-JiA"/>
                                </connections>
                            </tableViewCell>
                        </prototypes>
                        <sections/>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="7bK-jq-Zjz" id="Gho-Na-rnu"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="7bK-jq-Zjz" id="RA6-mI-bju"/>
                        </connections>
                    </tableView>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="Master" id="Zdf-7t-Un8"/>
                </tableViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Rux-fX-hf1" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="709" y="-630"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="r7l-gg-dq7">
            <objects>
                <navigationController id="vC3-pB-5Vb" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="DjV-YW-jjY">
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="JEX-9P-axG" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="GKi-kA-LjT"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="SLD-UC-DBI" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-45" y="129"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <inferredMetricsTieBreakers>
        <segue reference="6S0-TO-JiA"/>
    </inferredMetricsTieBreakers>
</document>
```

Storyboard of `test`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="9532" systemVersion="15D21" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" initialViewController="H1p-Uh-vWS">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="9530"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Master-->
        <scene sceneID="pY4-Hu-kfo">
            <objects>
                <navigationController title="Master" id="RMx-3f-FxP" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Pmd-2v-anx">
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="7bK-jq-Zjz" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="tsl-Nk-0bq"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="8fS-aE-onr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-20.266666666666666" y="-596.39999999999998"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Detail-->
        <scene sceneID="yUG-lL-AsK">
            <objects>
                <viewController title="Detail" id="JEX-9P-axG" customClass="DetailViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="svH-Pt-448">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" text="Detail view content goes here" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" minimumFontSize="10" id="0XM-y9-sOw">
                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="262" width="280" height="17"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" size="system"/>
                                <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="Detail" id="mOI-FS-AaM"/>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="detailDescriptionLabel" destination="0XM-y9-sOw" id="deQ-Na-JPF"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="FJe-Yq-33r" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="405.86666666666667" y="163.77333333333334"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Split View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="Nki-YV-4Qg">
            <objects>
                <splitViewController id="H1p-Uh-vWS" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="RMx-3f-FxP" kind="relationship" relationship="masterViewController" id="BlO-5A-QYV"/>
                        <segue destination="vC3-pB-5Vb" kind="relationship" relationship="detailViewController" id="Tll-UG-LXB"/>
                    </connections>
                </splitViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="cZU-Oi-B1e" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-456.5333333333333" y="-312.39999999999998"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Master-->
        <scene sceneID="smW-Zh-WAh">
            <objects>
                <tableViewController title="Master" clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear="NO" id="7bK-jq-Zjz" customClass="MasterViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="r7i-6Z-zg0">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <prototypes>
                            <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="blue" accessoryType="disclosureIndicator" hidesAccessoryWhenEditing="NO" indentationLevel="1" indentationWidth="0.0" reuseIdentifier="Cell" textLabel="Arm-wq-HPj" style="IBUITableViewCellStyleDefault" id="WCw-Qf-5nD">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="86" width="320" height="44"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="WCw-Qf-5nD" id="37f-cq-3Eg">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="287" height="43.5"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" text="Title" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="Arm-wq-HPj">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="15" y="0.0" width="270" height="43.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="20"/>
                                            <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                            <color key="highlightedColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                        </label>
                                    </subviews>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <segue destination="JEX-9P-axG" kind="push" identifier="showDetail" id="6S0-TO-JiA"/>
                                </connections>
                            </tableViewCell>
                        </prototypes>
                        <sections/>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="7bK-jq-Zjz" id="Gho-Na-rnu"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="7bK-jq-Zjz" id="RA6-mI-bju"/>
                        </connections>
                    </tableView>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="Master" id="Zdf-7t-Un8"/>
                </tableViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Rux-fX-hf1" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="378.13333333333333" y="-596.39999999999998"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="r7l-gg-dq7">
            <objects>
                <navigationController id="vC3-pB-5Vb" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="DjV-YW-jjY">
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="JEX-9P-axG" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="GKi-kA-LjT"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="SLD-UC-DBI" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-24" y="122.12"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <inferredMetricsTieBreakers>
        <segue reference="6S0-TO-JiA"/>
    </inferredMetricsTieBreakers>
</document>
```

So when I launch `test`, I got this error message :

```
2016-02-16 15:40:58.960 test[75054:13748065] -[DetailViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbe82c3c480
2016-02-16 15:40:58.964 test[75054:13748065] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbe82c3c480'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed14e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e78ddeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed1d48d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec6a90a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec6a4b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   test                                0x000000010e28c459 -[MasterViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 377
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010f7eaf01 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 369
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010f7ead5f -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010f7eb023 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010f204cee -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1775
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010f204fb3 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 388
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010f0cd4a2 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 317
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010f0e0c01 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 95
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010f0ecaf3 _afterCACommitHandler + 90
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec40367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec402d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec35f2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec35828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001124d1ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010f0c1610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    20  test                                0x000000010e28cc3f main + 111
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011145092d start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

It's the same with almost all my programs, so maybe I have not understood how view controllers work... I thought I had. Do you know why it's crashing like that ?

Comment: `DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];`??

Comment: `DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];` Why `topViewController` you're using here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't happen because of Auto Layout but Size Classes.
With Size Classes, your segue was of type Show Detail and was pointing to the UINavigationController that have DetailViewController as root view controller.
When you disable Auto Layout you disable Size Classes by default, and your Show Detail segue is automatically converted to a Push segue pointing directly at DetailViewController and not UINavigationController anymore.

So,

```
DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
```

won't work, because you are now dealing with an instance of DetailViewController and not UINavigationController. `topViewController` is a message that you can send to UINavigationController, but not DetailViewController.

Try

```
DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```

instead.

See the screenshots for better understanding.

[image: With Size Classes]

[image: Without Size Classes]

Comment: Thank you @robin ! Now I understand better how ViewControllers are linked to NavigationController. But I have only one DetailViewController, and when I switch to landscape mode (on iPad or iPhone 6+), I two Detail part of the screen. Is that because there are two separated view controllers ? So the wrong Detail view got filled up like that when I click on a cell : [screen](http://imgur.com/y9UmRnq)

Answer (score 0):

`[segue destinationViewController]` is of `id` type. This property contains the view controller whose contents should be displayed at the end of the segue. The line `[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController]` (inside your prepareForSegue:) crashes cause the `destinationViewController` doesn't have the `topViewController` selector/property implemented. The `topViewController` selector is normally sent to `UINavigationController`. So I guess(without seeing your other code) that UINavigationController is somehow involved in your flow. Autolayouts have nothing to do with this.

Just check for debug purpose:

```
if([segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]) { 
   //Should not crash
}
else {
   //Obviously you're doing something wrong
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code line `DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];` means your destination viewController has message `topViewController` which is not there.

So its not problem of `Autolayout`

Try this : `DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];`

also if you want to use `topViewController` then use `self.navigationController topViewController]` to get top object in stack of navigationViewController